# readP in Haskell has output that doesn't match the intended input when using the string

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, parser-combinators

I am trying to write a simple parser in Haskell using readP and following some pre-made code examples I have found.

I use the following:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))

t :: ReadP Int
t = (do string "0"
        return 0)
    <|>
    (do string "1"
        return 1)

parseString = readP_to_S (t >> eof)
```

However I get the following output:

```
ghci> parseString "1"
[((),"")]
ghci> parseString "0"
[((),"")]
ghci> parseString ""
[]
```

Whereas I would expect the following output

```
ghci> parseString "1"
[("1","")]
ghci> parseString "0"
[("0","")]
ghci> parseString ""
[]
```

How come that is? And is there a way to make it print these outputs instead?

Comment: `return ()` returns the dummy value `()`. You need something like `return 0` or `return 1` if you want the parser to produce the actual number. Also, you should really add types for your parsers with the intended output, e.g. `e :: Parser Int`. That will trigger a bunch of type errors, which will help you fixing your code. You might have other bugs, I'm unsure about what your parsers are intended to parse.

Comment: How can you give type signature in the sort of do blocks with `<|>` as used in the code above.

Comment: You should add a couple of examples of what you're trying to parse -- at least one example that *should* parse (plus what it should parse to); examples that *shouldn't* parse might also be helpful. Or if you've got a BNF grammar or something add that. Re type signatures, chi is telling you to write the type signatures that you think the functions *should* have, not the type signatures they actually have as you've written them; they assume there's a mismatch.

Comment: @neofelis I have now updated the post in order to try to clarify and answer what you are requesting. Hopefully I understood it correctly. I have added the types as well. And what I am looking for in the first place is just some very simple code that can give me a better understanding of `ReadP` since I can't see some good examples in the documentation: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html

Comment: And if anyone has some examples or know of somewhere where they gives examples of how to use the readP with the `ghci` similar to what they do with `parsec` here: https://youtu.be/iWpvKDFuCns  that would be very much appreciated since it could give me a more intuitive understanding of how the parser library works.

Comment: Thanks for improving the question! I'm unfortunately not aware of a tutorial on ReadP specifically, but honestly if you understand Parsec or Megaparsec, you'll understand ReadP too; those three libraries have a pretty similar API. Importantly, they all have Functor, Monad and Applicative instances, so once you understand Functor/Monad/Applicative a bit better they'll all become much simpler.

Comment: I have some understanding of Monad, Functors and Applicatives but I wouldnt say it is yet complete. Especially if there were some good hints for using `ReadP_to_S` with the interpreter that would be appreciated since I could then do it more interactively and test things: I have tried  `ReadP_to_S (ReadS "1")` but I get type constructor error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new code is better, but there is still an issue here

```
parseString input = runParser (e >> eof) input
                            --^^^^^^^^^^--
```

Adding `>> eof` discards the result of `e`. To retain it, we can either use

```
parseString input = runParser (e <* eof) input
```

Or, with a more basic approach:

```
whole :: Parser Int
whole = do
   val <- e       -- save the value produced by e
   eof            -- ensure the end of the parsed string
   return val     -- return the saved value

parseString input = runParser whole input
```

In either case, we get:

```
> parseString "1"
[(1,"")]
```

Note that the first component of the pair in the list is `1`, an `Int`. Indeed, it has the same type mentioned in the signature `whole :: Parser Int`.